# Pandas - Build sequnce in the group while resetting by fixed value - Issue in summary table

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I am resetting my flow by '000' when the patient sees that value in the pattern.But my summary table is mixing all patterns and giving only one value like shown in the out data frame. However, I like to show the same patient in all patterns individually shown the 'desired' data frame. Please help.

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'patient': ['one', 'one', 'one', 'one','one', 'one','one','one','one','one','one','one'],    
                    'pattern': ['A', 'B', '000', 'B', 'B', '000','D','A','C','000','A','B'],
                    'date': ['11/1/2022', '11/2/2022', '11/3/2022', '11/4/2022', '11/5/2022', '11/6/2022','11/7/2022', '11/8/2022', '11/9/2022','11/10/2022', '11/11/2022','11/12/2022']})


m = df2['pattern'] == '000'

display(df2)

out = (
        df2[~m].sort_values(['patient','date'],ascending=True)
                .groupby(["patient"])
                 .agg(pattern= ("pattern", ",".join),
                         patients=("patient", "nunique"))
                  .reset_index(drop=True)
                  .groupby(["pattern"]).agg({'patients':'sum'}).reset_index())


display(out)
```

I like to tweak my output to like below desired data frame:

```
desired = pd.DataFrame({'pattern': ['A,B', 'B,B', 'D,A,C'],    
                    'patients': [2, 1, 1]})

desired.head()
```

Answer (score 1):

You atre close, need new Series for grouping by mask with cumulative sum:

```
out = (df2[~m].sort_values(['patient','date'],ascending=True)
              .groupby(["patient", m.cumsum()])
              .agg(pattern= ("pattern", ",".join),
                   patients=("patient", "nunique"))
              .reset_index(drop=True)
              .groupby(["pattern"])
              .agg({'patients':'sum'})
              .reset_index())

print(out)
  pattern  patients
0     A,B         2
1     B,B         1
2   D,A,C         1
```